# cannot find function createDashboardItem in object Ti.UI ( Titanium Mobile )

Tags: titanium

i am creating simple dashboard view in which i using createDashboardItem function item has to set on dashboard.

code look something like this
error is on line 3 that function createDashboardItem not found
i am using Titanium Mobile SDK 1.6 and testing using android simulator SDK 2.2 API

i am creating simple dashboard view in which i using createDashboardItem function item has to set on dashboard.

code look something like this
error is on line 3 that function createDashboardItem not found
i am using Titanium Mobile SDK 1.6 and testing using android simulator SDK 2.2 API

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
var data = [];
var item = Titanium.UI.createDashboardItem({
    image:'/images/item1_off.png',
    selectedImage:'/images/item1_on.png',
    label:'Item 1'
});

data.push(item);
var dashboard = Titanium.UI.createDashboardView({
  data:data
});

win.add(dashboard);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because dashboard views are not currently implemented to Android platform.

As you can see in the Titanium API reference, there's no android icon right to the object name. [DashboardView](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.DashboardView-object.html)
Here you got an example of both android and apple platform compatible object :[Label](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Label-object)

DashboardView may be available in upcoming release, but for now, you'll have to create you own dashboards...

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I made my own (also, that little icon is *very* hard to miss)

The one thing that is missing from this example is the button listeners

```
var data = [];
var labels = ['events','dine','activities','kids','golf','casino','map','info','weather'];
for (var x=0;x<2;x++)
{
    for (var c=0;c<labels.length;c++)
    {
        if (Titanium.Platform.name == 'android') {
            var left = ((c%3)*100)+15;
            var top = (Math.floor(c/3) * 100) + 15

            var item = Titanium.UI.createButton({
                backgroundImage:'../img/icon_'+labels[c]+'.png',
                width:77,
                height:78,
                top:top,
                left:left
            }); 
            data.push(item);            
        } else {
            var item = Titanium.UI.createDashboardItem({
                image:'../img/icon_'+labels[c]+'.png'
                //label:labels[c]
            });
            data.push(item);
        }
    }
}

if (Titanium.Platform.name == 'android') {
    // Android Dashbaord
    var dashboard = Titanium.UI.createView({

    });
    for(var k=0; k<data.length; k++) {
        dashboard.add(data[k]);         
    }

} else {
    // iPhone Dashboard     
    var dashboard = Titanium.UI.createDashboardView({
        data:data,
        top:15
    });
}
```